# Magento2 How to upload excel file in adminform using uicomponent

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, upload

I need to create a button in custom form to upload the excel file. while saving the form need to save the excel data into custom table.

Can anyone have idea about this.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow The below link to upload CSV file using UI_Component

[Magento 2 Import CSV File to Custom Module Table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246831/magento-2-import-csv-file-to-custom-module-table)

Comment: I need a upload functionality from custom form not from import functionality

Comment: @Kavyacheerala Please read the article throughly you will also find the intended functionality in the answer section.